# Is my apple ID compromised after receiving notification of Facetime from unknown computer?

Tags: icloud, notifications, facetime

Hello I received this notification, I would like to know what to do next if I do not know the MacBook Pro the notification is referring to?  I have checked my icloud and do not see this device in the list.  I have since changed the password to the icloud and my email.  Any direction would be helpful.

Thank you

[image: Notification of facetime on unknown device]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That alert will popup every time someone link your Apple ID to a new device.

Short answer: if it's not your Mac, yes your account is compromised.

When you try to activate FaceTime or other Apple service on devices you have to log in using you Apple ID and password. So basically someone just entered this info.

First thing to do is to change your password, secret question and answer. Now double check your recovery email address and password associated to it.

After that every devices log off and prompt for the new Apple ID credentials. 
Now your account is safe.